# What would happen to a steel object that got cooled down nearly to absolute zero?

Tags: science-based, materials, cryogenics

Imagine a mundane steel object, it may be a door, a car, or simply a steel bar. By some handwavy means it gets nearly instantly cooled down to a a few milliKelvins. After that singular act of magic, physics takes over again (and it starts rapidly heating, I assume). What would happen to the object?

I honestly have no idea where to even start looking. I suspect there would be a lot of contraction/expansion strain involved, but how much, and what would it do? All the cryogenic experiments (at least those that I've found) are cooling down things quite slowly in comparison, and also frequently have mechanisms to specifically avoid thermal strain.

Also, I would prefer answers regarding common types of steel specifically. I know there are special steels for cryogenic use, and it would be probably slightly easier to answer what would happen to them. Still, answers regarding cryo-resistant steels or some other metals would be still useful to get the idea of what would happen.

Comment: Temperature difference induced stresses calculation was just the first question of a 60+ minutes oral exam when I was at the university. We had to calculate it on the blackboard, but the professor was nice enough to draw to the object. What is the object? What are its conditions? How big is it? How long is it kept at cryogenic temperature? (I accidentally spilled some liquid nitrogen on my shoes and nothing happened because it bounced off...). Without all this info we cannot answer.

Comment: This is a question that should be researched a little more before posting to the community. When I have physics questions, I often go to physics-specific forums to ask them. You will get downvoted here if you don't do adequate research before posting. Good luck!

Comment: If you take a small sphere of ordinary steel, such as a ball of a ball bearing, and cool it down to 1 millikelvin, then let it just lay on a wooden plate to warm up, nothing particularly spectacular will happen. The small ball will initially acquire a layer of frost; with time, the ball will come into thermal equilibrium with the surrounding air and the frost will melt. There will be no significant contraction or expansion strain. If you have in mind an object which is not a small steel sphere from a ball bearing, or some other scenario than placing it on a wooden plate, please specify.

Comment: P.S. A car is not a "steel object". A car is a complex machine, made of several distinct pieces, some of them steel, some of them glass, some of them plastic, some of them solid, some liquid. If you are seriously interested on how a regular motor car will fare being cooled at 1 millikelvin, that is a non-trivial research project. Try to apply to your national friendly science funding authority, and ask for a few hundred thousand dollars just to *design* your experiment. Try to be clear on what you expect to learn from the very expensive experiment.

Comment: Is the object's integrity protected when it's cooled down? Depending on how the "instant" freezing goes, the object may stay whole or shatter to small pieces.

Comment: That depends on whether the whole thing is cooled at once, or you attempt to cool it from the outside

Comment: For future reference, please don't waste our time with idle curiosity questions in this forum. Seriously: there is no worldbuilding context here and there's no research behind the question at all. We're here to help you build your fictional world, not chit chat about superfrozen iron. At the very least, ask this kind of question in one of the sciency forums where it's more likely to be on topic!

Comment: This site [permits real-world questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609) when asked in the context of worldbuilding per the [help]. However, we do still expect people to utilize the other Stacks that are more appropriate for such questions, when possible. However, had this been asked on [physics.se] and rejected, that would have justified asking it here (was it?).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for [physics.se].

Answer (score 2):

Well... assuming an average steel door, cooling it down instantly will result in a lot of stretching and stressing. Considering the fact, that steel contracts when cooled, it would probably shatter to pieces, large or small.

Comment: A ductile-to-brittle transition temperature will only help that process as well.

Comment: I am confident, that if the cooling happened instantly and uniformly, which is probably not possible in real world, the material would shatter into atoms, although it might be wrong, due to some quantum mechanics i am not aware of.